# What control simulate the view of ASP.NET DetailsView in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms

What is the best solution to display data as in ASP.NET DetailsView control in Windows Forms?

Answer (score 0):

There is no DetailsView control in WinForms. It does have the ability to create a Details Form. It is as simple as dropping a data source onto a form.

A good place to start is Data Sources Window at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ckyxa83(VS.80).aspx.

Specifically, "How to: Display Data in Individual Windows Forms Controls" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63h88ca4(v=VS.80).aspx.